# Plotly Radar Chart from ”circle” to polygon in R

Tags: r, plotly, radar-chart, spider-chart

i would like to create a radar chart using plotly but i was wondering if there is any way in R to have sides on the chart instead of being a circle.

I didnt write a code yet, im using the one that is in plotly’s website trying to find the way before implementing it on my data, so i cant attach dput().

I see that the standard output is something like this:

[Figure 1: Standard output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk2jj.png)

And i would like something more likely to this:

[Figure 2: Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7n3Y.png)

EDIT: Attaching a reproducible standard output

`````
````
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
    type = 'scatterpolar',
    r = c(39, 28, 8, 7, 28, 39),
    theta = c('A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'A'),
    fill = 'toself'
  ) 
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    polar = list(
      radialaxis = list(
        visible = T,
        range = c(0,50)
      )
    ),
    showlegend = F
  )

fig
````
`````

Comment: Hi Ayoubinsky, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. In other words, the data does not need to be from the source you are using, it just need to replicate the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : Add `gridshape = 'linear'` to `layout()`, this worked for me